# Update Model from Database, with LocalDb and |DataDirectory|

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, localdb

We're using EF 6, in database-first mode.

We've been building a database migration package, using FluentMigrator, and we've been running our migrations against empty LocalDb databases in our solution, for use in integration testing, etc.

Because we need our solutions to build wherever they're checked out, we've been using |DataDirectory| in the connection strings.

We've written some unit [sic] tests, running against LocalDb instances, running the migrations first to ensure that the tests are running against the current schema.  (Yes, these are integration tests, but we're using a unit test framework, and I don't want to argue about it.)

What I would like to do next is to change our configuration so that when we run "Update Model from Database" on our .edmx files, it's the LocalDb instance that the tool looks to. And I can't make that work.

My guess is that whatever tool is running, when we do this, doesn't have it's DataDirectory set where I need it to be, in it's appdomain.

Does anyone know what tool this might be?  And how I can configure it to connect to a localdb instance, that's using |DataDirectory| to create a relative path?